# How to deploy files into MarkLogic server

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am new to Marklogic database. I try to retrieve data through CTS queries. I have created an html and an xqy file in Eclipse. How do I deploy my files into MarkLogic server?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly encourage you to take some of [MarkLogic University's classes](http://www.marklogic.com/training/) -- they are free and available online. Also, take a look at the available [guides](http://docs.marklogic.com/) and [tutorials](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn).

For your specific question, I suggest you begin by reading [Getting Started With MarkLogic XQuery Applications](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/getting-started/xquery).