# ERROR: Page Not Found - when trying to install new REST extension in ML7

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to learn REST API in ML7 (we cannot upgrade to ML8 to get all the new features), so I can just add what I need.

I was trying to install simple rest-api extension that would supposedly resolve forest id to its name but it doesn't work as expected.
I'm authenticated in curl PUT but the return html code gives me:

```
Welcome, <username>
Page Not Found
```

Command that I'm executing is:

```
curl --anyauth --user user:pass -X PUT -H "Content-type: application/xquery" -d@"./resolvefidtoname.xqy" http://localhost:8002/resolvefidtoname
```

and the code in xquery file is:

```
$ cat resolvefidtoname.xqy
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace ernest = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource /resolvefidtoname";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
    at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

declare function ernest:resolvefidtoname($node as element()) as element()?
{
  if (fn:data($node) ne 0) then
    element {fn:node-name($node)}
    {
      xdmp:forest-name(fn:data($node))
    }
  else ()
};
```

I'm kind of stumped. I'm starting to think that our application that was bootstrapped to work on different port than 80002 is not configured to take advantage of rest-api but I don't know how to test that.

I thought that maybe by using curl command I can test if application on given port supports rest-api, so I tried:

```
curl -X GET --anyauth --user user:pass -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8002/LATEST/rest-apis/
```

but that resulted with answer:
    {"rest-apis":[]} 
which is not very helpful and when tested on any other listening ports there was no response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm running ML6 on AmazonLinux, installation is from ML ec2 cfn template (nothing fancy).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for trying it out. There are a few issues.

A REST extension is installed and executed on the port for your REST server and not on port 8002 (which is the port for the Management REST API).

The URI for installing an extension on a REST server is different from the curl commands above:

http://docs.marklogic.com/6.0/REST/PUT/v1/config/resources/%5Bname%5D

The module namespace has an embedded space:

```
"http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource /resolvefidtoname"
                                       ^
```

For more background, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/6.0/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_59112

And also the free training resources Dave Cassel lists in the answer to:

[How to deploy files into MarkLogic server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143305/deploying-files-to-marklogic-server)

By the way, MarkLogic 6 is two releases old.  You would get many new features and fixes by using MarkLogic 8 if possible.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for confusion. I just noticed that I have a typo. I'm using ML7. I think after going through soo many documentations, forums I had information overload.. People were pointing me to the wrong documentation links and I think I got confused myself as well. I know that documentation for ML8 is different from docs for ML7 (which is what we have).

Thank you for your response, I'll check if these links work for ML7.

Comment: I modified port and I think I'm getting further but now I get errors in the log like:
"RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid extension.."
Any ideas now?

Thank you

Comment: RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT sounds like MarkLogic didn't like the contents of the source file. Make sure you match the [Resource Extension Interface](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_75991).